# What units does OCI-Lob::size() use?

Tags: php, oracle

Browsing through the PHP documentation for the Oracle OCI8 functions I found OCI-Lob::size [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oci-lob.size.php). Its description says: "Gets the size of the large object". The description of the return value is "Returns length of large object value or FALSE on failure. Empty objects have zero length".

This could be very useful to me, but it is not clear what units are used. Characters? Bytes? Kilobytes? Larger blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a little bit tricky in OCI itself. For BLOBs it's obvious - bytes. Just beware Oracle LOBs start with the 1st byte. (not from zero). For CLOBs it returns chars.

But OciLobRead/OciLobWrite return number of bytes written regardless on lob type. There were new functions introduced - OciLobRead2/OciLobWrite2 they return both positions(in bytes, in chars).

Comment: Not sure if I can access OciLobRead2 from PHP. Or do you mean that PHP's methods for LOBs cann OciLobRead2?

Comment: It depends on the client version used for the drivers' compilation. See [link](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/oci8/oci8_lob.c#L327)